# Easiest way to verify MyBatis 3.x caching is working properly

Tags: java, mybatis

Greetings!
I'm trying to set up caching for a small MyBatis & Spring app and following their pdf doc my xml mapper contains

```
<cache />
```

Configuration xml file at the top has settings as follows:

```
    <settings>
    <setting name="cacheEnabled" value="true" />
</settings>
```

logging with log4j is set for DEBUG, but I see no indications that cache is working as expected.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I can't make it work and I'm on 3.4.5. Can't understand...

Comment: Well the cache must also be globally enabled. Documentation as always is not clear. CacheExecutor will be used only if globally enabled, and then, when a cache won't be found the query will be delegated to a SimpleExecutor. I had to debug first hand to understand something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... that was easy:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.ibatis=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.ibatis.common.jdbc.SimpleDataSource=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.ibatis.common.jdbc.ScriptRunner=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientDelegate=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.ibatis.cache.decorators.LoggingCache=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.Connection=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.Statement=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.PreparedStatement=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.ResultSet=DEBUG
```

... the rest: not so much. Just can't get the caching to work.

I think it's time to switch to something else. Check out their mailing list and draw your own conclusions.